# Add color scheme to VS2015 drop down menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This may not be (most likely not) the correct StackExchange site, but I couldn't find the one that I thought would be more correct.  If there is a better site just comment with it and I'll gladly delete this question and move it.

What I'm trying to achieve is getting color schemes added to the `Color theme:` drop down menu inside of Visual Studio's `Options -> Environment -> General -> Visual experience`.  Is this possible? What is involved?

[image: Visual experience]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very much possible, use the extension [Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f4b51b6-5c6b-4a81-9cb5-f2daa560430b) from Microsoft

Comment: Is the editor needed or can one simply add color-scheme files manually?